# ExtJs 4.2 - Change proxy configuration of a store dynamically?

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a grid which I use at 2 places:

1. A page which shows all values - A separate store is used for this, which has an `xyz` directfn
2. As a part of another page, where an identifier is passed to the grid - This again uses a separate store and an `abc` directfn

I'm trying to use the same store since the functionalities are almost the same. I want to change the configuration dynamically in such a way, that when the 1st scenario is in picture, the store should use the `xyz` directfn and for the 2nd scenario it should use the `abc` directfn with a parameter.

How to achieve this?

Comment: When you initialize the store, you can just set the function to whichever one you want, depending on whatever conditions you want. I can give you a more specific example if you add you code to your question

Comment: I have restructured my question, please see now!